# What is the best way to select attributes for all members of an AD LDAP group from PHP?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I need to select a number of attributes for all of the users in a particular group from a PHP application. I realize that I could query the 'member' attribute of the group to get the dn of every member and then make a separate LDAP query for the attributes of each member. I am hoping however, that there is a single query that I can perform that would return all of the results at once however, in order to prevent excess back-and-forth between the PHP app and the LDAP server (AD).

Using an [LDAP browser](http://www.google.com/search?q=ldap+browser+Jarek+Gawor) I can successfully run a search over my full domain:

```
Search DN:  DC=middlebury,DC=edu
Filter: (memberOf=CN=BG_Cells,OU=General,OU=Groups,DC=middlebury,DC=edu)
Attributes: objectClass,mail,givenName,sn,sAMAccountName,telephoneNumber
```

and get back the expected results. When I try this filter using PHP's `ldap_search()` method however, I get an `Operations error` with code `1`.

Below is the PHP I'm using.

```
....
$baseDN = 'DC=middlebury,DC=edu';
$filter = '(memberOf=CN=BG_Cells,OU=General,OU=Groups,DC=middlebury,DC=edu)';
$attributes = array('objectClass','mail','givenName','sn','sAMAccountName','telephoneNumber');

$result = ldap_search($connection, $baseDN, $filter, $attributes);

if (ldap_errno($connection))
    print "Read failed for $filter with message: ".ldap_error($connection).", #".ldap_errno($ connection));
```

Other filters work just fine with these attributes and using just `array('mail')` or an empty array for the attributes does not get rid of the error result, so I'm sure the problem is with my filter rather than the connection or attribute set.

A second option would be to do one query for the group member dns in the 'member' field of the group and then build a long OR query with every member dn. This still would involve two queries however.

So is there a better way to get each member's attributes, ideally in one query?

Comment: Please post the relevant piece of code.

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell, but typically, LDAP result code (1) indicates that the associated request was out of sequence with another operation in progress (e.g., a non-bind request in the middle of a multi-stage SASL bind). It does not indicate that the client has sent an erroneous message.

Are you bound over the connection before performing the query?
-jim

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where exactly is the problem, in the filter or the attributes selection. If it's the attribution selection. If it's the filter, then I suggest you put the attribute selection aside now as a way of isolating the problem.

Could you show the code of the relevant `ldap_search()` you are executing?

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant PHP.

Other filters work just fine with these attributes and using just array('mail') or an empty array for the attributes does not get rid of the error result, so I'm sure the problem is with my filter rather than the connection or attribute set.